# XSLT UDT, limit number of outputs per group after sorting

Tags: xslt

I managed to sort my items according to their category but now i would like to limit the number of items get shown per category. This is what i got so far:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="udt:Data[count(. | key('data-by-Cat', udt:Cat)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:sort select="udt:Zap" />
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3>
          <xsl:value-of select="udt:Cat" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </h3>
      <xsl:variable name="currentData" select="key('data-by-Cat', udt:Cat)" />
      <xsl:if test="$currentData">
        <div class="my-item-container">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData" mode="list">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here an example of my XML:

```
<UserDefinedTable>
    <Data>
        <UserDefinedRowId>4057</UserDefinedRowId>
        <Title>Item title 1</Title>
        <Cat>Category 1</Cat>
        <Link>google.com</Link>
    </Data> 
</UserDefinedTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is this...

```
<xsl:variable name="currentData" select="key('data-by-Cat', udt:Cat)[position() &lt;= 10]" />
```

Alternatively, should you wish to use `$currentData` in other places without a limit, you could put the condition on the `xsl:apply-templates` instead

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData[position() &lt;= 10]" mode="list">
```

Comment: The alternative solution is what i wanted :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line below the `xsl:sort` tag:

```
<xsl:if test="not(position() > 10)">
```

This will show you only 10 items.

You can do it without not():

```
<xsl:if test="position() < 3">
```

And if you have problems with the `'<' '>'` symbols, use  `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: If i put it after sort that will limit the number of categories it shows, i want to limit the number of items in each category

Comment: @mheonyae Could you share with us a little example of the XML that you want to transform?

Comment: <UserDefinedTable>
   <Data>
      <UserDefinedRowId>4057</UserDefinedRowId>
      <Title>Item title 1</Title>
      <Cat>Category 1</Cat>
      <Link>http://google.com</Link>
 
   </Data>
</UserDefinedTable> here is a sample.